# Change main endpoint in Spring Data Rest (usind Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Im building a small application using Spring (Boot, Data, Data Rest).
I have some JpaRepositories that aumotatically are exported as Rest endpoints.
What i want to do is to change the base path from / to /api.
Now to list all people for example i do a GET to `http://localhost:8080/people` and i want the url to be `http://localhost:8080/api/people`.

I tried adding this config class but nothing happened (it seems that Spring Boot overrides this config):

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
{
    return new Class<?>[] { Application.class};
}
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
{
    return new Class<?>[] { RestExporterRestConfig.class, RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class };
}
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings()
{       
    return new String[] { "/api/*" };
}   
}
```

My **Application.java**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import(RestExporterRestConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

and **RestExporterRestConfig**:

```
@Configuration
public class RestExporterRestConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Override
protected void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
    v.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator());
}

@Bean
@Qualifier
public DefaultFormattingConversionService defaultConversionService() {
    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
    conversionService.addConverter(StringToDate.INSTANCE);
    return conversionService;
}

@Bean
public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter() {
    return new DomainClassConverter<DefaultFormattingConversionService>(defaultConversionService());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured it out. SpringWebAppInitializer is not necesary in this case. I just added this code to Application.java:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet)     {
    ServletRegistrationBean reg = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    reg.addUrlMappings("/api/*");

    return reg;
}
```

I think this is the correct way to modify (add, change mappings, etc) servlets using Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes but to change the existing `DispatcherServlet` path you only need to set "server.servletPath=api/".

Comment: Thanks. Obviosuly the cleaner solution.